# How do I convert box shadow from CSS to Flutter

Tags: css, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I convert this box shadow to Flutter?

box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(27, 31, 95, 0.4);

shadow

[image]

Comment: is it only having bottom shadow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BoxShadow`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html) on [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html),

```
 Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 500,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    boxShadow: [
      ///modify the way you like, you can have more
      BoxShadow( 
        color: shadowColor,
        blurRadius: 4,
        offset: Offset(0, 4),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

As for the look, the UI is similar to [`Card`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html) widget

```dart
Card(
  elevation: 4, //use it
  child: SizedBox(),
),
```